# No rest api credentials in developer site

Tags: paypal

Does anyone know, where can I find clientId and secret to sandbox account in paypal? I was looking at developer site in account details, but there is only username, password and signature, nothing more.. At sandbox site I can find only certificate or signature generating... I've read that someone couldn't find classical API credentials.. but I have opposite situation.. :<

There is image addres with account details - there is nothing about Rest API credentials.. :/

http://pbrd.co/19lLQza

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK

The answer is here : 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_credentials/

If you want to have test application with rest api credentials, you have to make life application (where is sens in that? I really do not know -.-) and in details you will have life credentials and test rest API credentials...